# Disabling foreign key constraint in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, foreign-keys

Attempting to disable foreign key constraint. This is what the create users table looks like as of right now. Attempted to use the method disableForeignKeyConstraints, but no luck when migrating. I also tried using the enableForeignKeyConstraints method after the create schema, but that also didn't help. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Blog Post Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $blog_posts = BlogPost::all();
    return view('whatsnew.index', compact("blog_posts"));
}

public function show($blog_post){
    $blog_post = BlogPost::find($blog_post);
    return view('whatsnew.show', compact("blog_post"));
}

public function create(){
    return view('whatsnew.create');
}

public function store(BlogPostRequest $request){
    $formData = $request->all();

    BlogPost::create($formData);

    return redirect('whatsnew');
}

public function edit($blog_post){
    $blog_post = BlogPost::findOrFail($blog_post);

    return view('whatsnew.edit', compact("blog_post"));
}

public function update(BlogPostRequest $request, $blog_post){
    $formData = $request->all();
    $blog_post = BlogPost::findOrFail($blog_post);
    $blog_post->update($formData);

    return redirect('whatsnew');
}

public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' =>['create', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
}

public function destroy(BlogPost $blog_post){
    $blog_post->delete();
    return redirect('whatsnew');
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to disable the foreign key constraints?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It is causing errors, won't let me create a blog post for example, I will post a screenshot of the error

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the `users` migration. Please post code that creates the blog post.

Comment: the error means when you are creating a new post, you are not giving it the `user_id` for the post

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Just posted the controller

Comment: Where should the `user_id` come from? From the session?